# Use SED to convert specific column lower to upper case

Tags: shell, sed, uppercase

I must to convert the 4 column to upper case with only one sed command.

```
user,gender,age,native_lang,other_lang
0,M,19,finnish,english swedish german 
1,M,30,urdu,english 
2,F,26,finnish,english swedish german
3,M,20,finnish,english french swedish 
4,F,20,finnish,english swedish
```

This it's my best movement but change all columns.

```
sed -e 's/\(.*\)/\U\1/'
```

I really want understand the command, but I really lose myself why use" \ " or how to read it.

Comment: Without converting header: `sed -E 's/([0-9],[a-z]+)/\U\1/' file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed 's/^\(\([^,]*,\)\{3\}\)\([^,]*\)/\1\U\3/' # POSIX BRE
sed -E 's/^(([^,]*,){3})([^,]*)/\1\U\3/'      # POSIX ERE
```

See [an online demo](https://ideone.com/dGppHs):

```sh
s='user,gender,age,native_lang,other_lang
0,M,19,finnish,english swedish german 
1,M,30,urdu,english 
2,F,26,finnish,english swedish german
3,M,20,finnish,english french swedish 
4,F,20,finnish,english swedish '
sed 's/^\(\([^,]*,\)\{3\}\)\([^,]*\)/\1\U\3/' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
user,gender,age,NATIVE_LANG,other_lang
0,M,19,FINNISH,english swedish german 
1,M,30,URDU,english 
2,F,26,FINNISH,english swedish german
3,M,20,FINNISH,english french swedish 
4,F,20,FINNISH,english swedish
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(([^,]*,){3})` - Group 1: three repetitions of any zero or more chars other than a comma and then a comma
- `([^,]*)` - Group 3: zero or more chars other than a comma.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/[^,]*/\U&/4' file
```

Uppercase the fourth set of non-commas.

---

If not the headers, use:

```
sed '1!s/[^,]*/\U&/4' file
```